# What does the number in linux/Unix file permissions like "-rw-rw-r--. 1"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions, ls

I am Linux student, I am learning Linux permission system for user and group. one thing is still unclear, when I check permission using `ls -l` command it shows a numerical value with permission detail like this 
`-rw-rw-r--. 1  ...`

**So my question is:**

What does that numerical value means in `ls -l` output

Though it will be more pleasure to have some explanation with the answer as I am a new bee.

I have tried to find the answer from book, and searched the same question on stack-overflow. But not getting the understanding.

Comment: Number of [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1 indicates the number of links. The definition of link varies among platforms, however you may assume it is the count of hard links to this entry.

Comment: May I know what type of links? Yet I am unaware of such links philosophy in Linux?

Comment: An entry in the file system can be referenced multiple times for several reasons: for example you would like to place a subtree which is located in a certain path, under another path because some users cannot reach the first path. Links can be hard or symbolic. You may refer to this guide which explains in detail what you ask: https://opensource.com/article/17/6/linking-linux-filesystem

Comment: Note that "number of links" in `ls` output only counts hard links, not symbolic links.

Comment: You are right. I have edited the answer.